# spark read from different account s3 and write to my account s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have spark job which needs to read the data from s3 which is in other account**(Data Account)** and process that data.

once its processed it should write back to s3 which is in my account.

So I configured access and secret key of **"Data account"** like below in my spark session

```
val hadoopConf=sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.access.key","DataAccountKey")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key","DataAccountSecretKey") 
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com")
System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")

val df = spark.read.json("s3a://DataAccountS/path")
/* Reading is success */

df.take(3).write.json("s3a://myaccount/test/")
```

with this reading is fine, but I am getting below error when writing.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 301, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: A5E574113745D6A0, AWS Error Code: PermanentRedirect, AWS Error Message: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

but If I dont configure  details of Data Account and try to write some dummy data to my s3 from spark it works.

So how should I configure to make both reading from different account s3 and writing to my account s3 works

Comment: Not really a Spark issue, but rather an AWS permission issue. You need to grant write access on the S3 bucket in you own account for the Data account. Checkout the AWS documentation on how to set write access for an S3 bucket for another account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [s3 bucket policy for instance to read from two different accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246014/s3-bucket-policy-for-instance-to-read-from-two-different-accounts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your spark classpath has hadoop-2.7 JARs on, you can use secrets-in-Paths as the technique, so a URL like `s3a://DataAccountKey:DataAccountSecretKey/DataAccount/path`. Be aware this will log the secrets everywhere.

Hadoop 2.8+ JARs will tell you off for logging your secrets everywhere, but adds per-bucket binding

`spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.DataAccount.access.key DataAccountKey
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.DataAccount.secret.key DataAccountSecretKey
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.DataAccount.endpoint s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com`

then for all interaction with that bucket, these per-bucket options will override the main settings.

Note: if you want to use this, don't think dropping hadoop-aws-2.8.jar into your classpath will work, you'll only get classpath errors. All of hadoop-* JAR needs to go to 2.8 and the aws-sdk updated too.

Comment: I am using Horton cluster so Updating  hadoop-* JAR to 2.8 will be difficult job. is there any way where if I configure s3 bucket policy will work ?

Comment: YES! As I wrote in my comment above - you can grant permissions on your bucket. See AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Comment: @user3607698 if you are using HDP2.6 then the per-bucket stuff is already in

Comment: @stevel You are life saver, thank you.
In case you are looking for official documentation, here it is:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configuring_different_S3_buckets_with_Per-Bucket_Configuration

Comment: @NameNotFoundException good to hear! If you are trying to debug configs, grab my cloudstore jar and use its storediag tool, which not only (safely) prints the resolved values , it shows where they came from https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore