# s3 bucket policy for instance to read from two different accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a instance which needs to read data from two different account s3.

1. Bucket in **DataAccount** with bucket name "**dataaccountlogs**"
2. Bucket in **UserAccount** with bucket name "**userlogs**"

I have console access to both account, so now I need to configure bucket policy to allow instances to read s3 data from buckets **dataaccountlogs** and **userlogs** , and my instance is running in  **UserAccount** .

I need to access these two bucket both from **command line** as well as using **spark job**.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/ ?

Comment: I had requested other account owner to update the policy, mean time I want to know if add those policy will I be able read that s3 in side spark without any configuring access key and secret key ?

Comment: where is this spark job running ? if EC2, then you need appropriate IAM role attached to it.

Comment: yes, it is running in EC2 instance of my account . but I am not sure which which I am role I should be attached to it

Answer (score 1):

You will need a role in UserAccount, which will be used to access mentioned buckets, say RoleA. Role should have permissions for required S3 operations.

Then you will able to configure a bucket policy for each bucket:

1. For **DataAccount**:

   ```
   {        
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "test1",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": {
               "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::DataAccount:role/RoleA"
           },
           "Action": "s3:*",
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::dataaccountlogs",
               "arn:aws:s3:::dataaccountlogs/*"
           ]
       }
   ]
   }
   ```
2. For **UserAccount**:

   ```
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "test1",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": {
               "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::DataAccount:role/RoleA"
           },
           "Action": "s3:*",
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::userlogs",
               "arn:aws:s3:::userlogs/*"
           ]
       }
   ]
   }
   ```

**For accessing them from command line:**

You will need to setup AWS CLI tool first:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/setup-aws-cli.html

Then you will need to configure a profile for using your role.
First you will need to make a profile for your user to login:

> aws configure --profile YourProfileAlias

And follow instructions for setting up credentials.

Then you will need to edit config and add profile for a role:
~/.aws/config

Add to the end a block:

```
[profile YourRoleProfileName]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::DataAccount:role/RoleA
source_profile = YourProfileAlias
```

After that you will be able to use **aws s3api ... --profile YourRoleProfileName** to access your both buckets on behalf of created role.

**To access from spark:**

1. If you run your cluster on EMR, you should use SecurityConfiguration, and fill a section for S3 role configuration. A different role for each specific bucket can be specified. You should use "Prefix" constraint and list all destination prefixes after. Like "s3://dataaccountlogs/,s3://userlogs".

**Note:** you should strictly use s3 protocol for this, not s3a. Also there is number of limitations, you can find here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-s3-optimized-committer.html

2. Another way with spark is to configure Hadoop to assume your role. Putting

   > spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider = 
   >   "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider,org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider"

And configuring you role to be used

> spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn = arn:aws:iam::DataAccount:role/RoleA

This way is more general now, since EMR commiter have various limitations. You can find more information for configuring this at Hadoop docs:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/assumed_roles.html

Comment: hadn't thought of using AssumedRole for that purpose, nice trick. It primarily went in so we could test permission problems better, especially failure partway through rename or delete.
In spark, those options should all be `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a`....

Comment: Thanks @SteveLoughran. I fixed in the answer.

Comment: @SteveLoughran If you need to provide multiple external accounts access  to your account bucket/s, you don't even need a bucket policies. You can just provide to a role in your account permissions to access required bucket/s, and share the role with multiple accounts.